# Android/iOS Alert Feature

Tags: android, ios

Is it possible to send an alert when you are 50m-100m within a specific area. For instance if you are within 100 meters of a certain restaurant the application will alert you.

Regards,

Ryan

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing.html

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like [iBeacon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBeacon) may be worth looking into. Using Bluetooth Low Energy, you can detect when a phone passes near a beacon device and take action, accordingly.

So the simple answer is "yes" this is possible. There are apps like [shopkick](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.shopkick.app) that offer rewards and deals based on your proximity to stores. That app just uses coarse and fine grained location information on the phone (think: GPS) to make that work.

So not only is this doable, there are many apps in market already using that approach. It's commonly referred to as "geofencing."

Comment: Hey Thanks for your answer I will look into iBeacons. Also do you have any alternatives?

Comment: No matter how you slice it, you will need the user to have your app preinstalled (before arriving at the desired location). If they have your app, then the easiest thing is probably just to use the app to monitor their location. When it matches the restaurant then send the alert. The buzzword for this kind of thing is [geofencing](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/Geofence.html). You may want to look into each platform's support for geofences.

Comment: I don't know about iOS, but Android has 2 built in Geofencing APIs that use GPS and network location-  Geofence and addProximityAlert